# Simulation - Discrete Phase Change

Tags: python, simulation

I have a question of how best to approach a problem, I hope this isn't too general. The type of process I'm trying to model is described in the table below:

[image: Sample Process]

We have a process that we're seeking to move all A's to C's, but we essentially have a fixed budget (how many A's we can move to C). At the same time, without any intervention, C's will become B's, and B's will become A's.

So, the question I'm asking is: what is the modeling / simulation process I'd need to utilize to attack this problem (e.g., discrete event, phase change, etc.)

Comment: I'm not clear on what your desiderata are here. The transition 'budgets'? The time to move all As?

Comment: The time will depend on the "budget". If you have an unlimited budget, you can move all A's and B's to C.

Comment: I know, I was just using it as an off-the-cuff example. But I still don't understand what exact *problem* you're trying to solve using whatever approach you might eventually choose.

Comment: We have a goal of moving all sites in buckets A and B to bucket C. However, there is a cost to do doing this. Plus, without any intervention, all items when end up in bucket A due to deteriorating conditions....which is why we need to spend "budget" to start moving them down to C, reallocating the budget along the way to focus more C's to keep them C's

Comment: Does that help clarify?

Comment: ...you've just reposted a part of your original post as a comment to that post.